# Debounce function failed test

Tags: javascript

I have the next debounce function:

```js
export const debounce = (func: (...args: string[]) => void, wait: number) => {
  let timeout: NodeJS.Timeout;
  function executedFunction(...args: string[]) {
    const later = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      func(...args);
    };

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  }

  return executedFunction;
};
```

My scope is to test this function:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers();
describe('test debounce function', () => {
    test('execute just once', () => {
        const func = jest.fn();
        const debouncedFunc:any = debounce(func, 500);

        // Execute for the first time
        debouncedFunc();

        // Move on the timer
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(250);
        // try to execute a 2nd time
        debouncedFunc();

        // Fast-forward time
        jest.runAllTimers();

        expect(func).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
})
```

Trying to test in the way above i get `TypeError: debouncedFunc is not a function`, but i don't understand why. Could somebody help with testing the above function?

Answer (score 1):

Your debounce function has an error. The last statement:

```
return executedFunction();
```

...already schedules the *execution* of the function -- which it shouldn't -- and it returns `undefined`. It should instead *return* the function, not execute it:

```
return executedFunction;
```

Comment: thanks, i changed, but now in my test i get `Received number of calls: 0` and my test does not pass. Could you help?